# It is possible to use Spring Security tag <sec:authentication> inside jsf view?

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

It is possible to use Spring Security (3.1.0) with JSF (2.0)? …in concrete, tag `<sec:authentication>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html). They say basically that you need to define a custom taglib.xml and register it in your web.xml

Comment: I have already followed that doc. And it works for sec:authorize tag, but not for sec:authentication tag.
Also, it only works for Spring Security 3.0.5, not for the latest 3.1.0.
Thank you anyway

Comment: Did you find a solution to your answer ? I'm stuck with the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387228/spring-security-3-1-4-taglib-authorize-authentication-are-not-working-with-role . Bye